# how can I express 3cos(30) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

It looks like the only way to approach geomatry expression from javascript is Math object.

but I can't express 3cos(30) although cos(30) can be expressed as Math.cos(30).

how can I express 3cos(30) in javascript?

Comment: What do you mean by 3cos(30)?

Comment: What about `2.598076211353315940`? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `3cos(30)` mean three times the cosine of 30? In that case, you can compute it like this:

```
var result = 3 * Math.cos(30);
```

Edit: Note that `cos()` expects it parameter to be in radians, not degrees.

Answer (score 2):

if `30` is `30 degrees` you should convert it in radians with `Math.PI` ([π](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi))

```
radians = degrees * (π/180)
```

so

```
30 * π/180 => 30° = π/6
```

and your formula

```
3 * Math.cos(Math.PI/6)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `3cos(30)` is `3 x Cos(30)` :

```
3 * Math.cos(30)
```